# What is the dll or sys file that installs networking components at Windows Setup?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, installation

I am writing a research about Windows XP, but i cant find out about the file/step that installs networking components at Windows XP Setup.

[image: Screenshot of the step]

I know that the root of it is setup.exe, but setup.exe runs other dlls, like setupapi.dll, syssetup.dll and so on. Does anyone knows about the dll or other file that installs networking components at Windows Setup? Like, the name of the dll, or is the step located in other dll/sys file?